# Why is the incorrect output being appended to my python file?

Tags: python, text-files

I have the python file trying to modify the other python file here:

```
file = "PythonFile1.py"

with open(file, "r") as current_file:
    lines = current_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line != 'sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")' or line != "sys.stdout.close()" or line != "import sys":
        del lines[lines.index(line)]
with open(file, "w") as current_file:
    for line in lines:
        current_file.write(line)

print(lines)
```

And here is the python file trying to be modified:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")
sys.stdout.close()
```

When I run the first python file I get this result in my other python file.

```
sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")
```

I am looking for the contents of the file to be:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")
sys.stdout.close()
```

I am not sure why it is not catching the lines I want to stay, can anyone help resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not good practice to change code with code. There must be a better way to structure your code so it doesn't need to be modified. Seems you're asking the wrong question here. See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I am using it for a discord bot that will ask for the code to write and it will write it to the file, but I need those lines to stay so the output will go to a .txt, which I can then use to send the output.

Comment: Are you planning to run their code?

Comment: `sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")` is that real python? i don't think that does what you want it to.

Comment: Yes. I am planning to run their code.

Comment: What is the sys.stout for? Are you wanting to print the contents of the modified file?

Comment: Does it matter? I do not believe I am asking for your criticism, but rather how to delete all the lines from a file, except if the lines are specific code.

Comment: Well sorry if it sounded like criticism because it definitely wasn't, your said that you were "looking for the correct code" of that part, so I was just trying to clarify what that is for

Comment: Not you, you answer was helpful, but not the answer to the question.

Comment: They point out stuff not related to the question, and it is quite annoying, especially because they don't feel like solving it. Another reason why Stack Overflow is not so beginner friendly.

Comment: Well the "correct code" part threw me for a loop. It reads like you want that part of the code fixed.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say correct contents of the file, let me edit that.

Comment: if you have the contents that you want, why not overwrite the file directly? In other words, don't delete and keep lines selectively. Instead "nuke and pave" the file

Comment: What is the action of "nuke and pave"?

Comment: completely overwrite the file with the contents that you want

Comment: That is going to work, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```py
magic_lines = [
    "sys.stdout = open('test.txt', 'w')",
    "sys.stdout.close()",
    "import sys"
]

with open(infilepath, 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

with open(infilepath, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() in magic_lines:
            outfile.write(line)
```

But it sounds like to me you could nuke and pave the file completely:

```py
from textwraps import dedent

with open(infilepath, 'w') as infile:
    infile.write(dedent("""\
        import sys
        sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")
        sys.stdout.close()
    """))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(file, "w") as current_file:
    current_file.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

You don't need to loop through it and write them, just join the lines and write once directly. When you are looping though it, each and every loop you are replacing what was already in the file, unless you use append mode. Join the lines together and write them directly will be easier.

---

[Read more about the join method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/)

Comment: That's not true. He is not opening the file inside the loop. He is opening once and then writing in a loop. That's completely standard

Comment: What do you mean @Tomerikoo?  I was talking about the part where OP is writing to the file with new changes

Comment: I am talking about what you said: *each and every loop you are replacing what was already in the file*. That's not true. That be true if he was opening the file with `'w'` inside the loop and that truncates the file each time... He is simply writing to the file in a loop, there is nothing wrong with that. After each write the pointer advances, the only thing missing is maybe a `'\n'` at each write